# Error Could not deserialize key data when Using RSA Algorithm Django Rest Framework Simple JWT

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I got an error when using django rest framework and simple jwt authentication with RSA algorithm.

When I'm using HS algorithm my code works very well but when I change the algorithm to RS I got the following error:

> Could not deserialize key data. The data may be in an incorrect format or it may be encrypted with an
> unsupported algorithm.

My Settings:

```py
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ALGORITHM': 'RS512',
    'SIGNING_KEY' : 'ssh-rsa MIIBPAIBAAJBALZ+WuuTIol2cwEALcqn+/d0AER+sX269KVZt7sdl9C0QcspNHvHGYBWLoYIV5i72fsINX4V5IvkqsIn83O4jQMCAwEAAQJBAJ8E/Y73GAo2V8IQeNZ1iH646x7EUz9e8J1Az3PSNp7ZZ4tNjEhyA817qQGT9nfvRPXqIKkKFVe0THfmWmbK5cECIQD4M/qhoT2n99iIJwJq2DhbVvqx74hal+ocuboSwDZuIwIhALw58q4+YZlg79fGc2PyK8MUQLIx/i+O3bK7moMCf6OhAiEA04E/15IWf1clzsgnODMuuy9AjHaJJGIGHxpppObkuy8CIGqjwhRqD02gmAH90x5K8/RAIy9SF5rGLGC43R9gaQRBAiEAoLxLZuvXosXy6XR67ODCgZI7yB1XXVIwB73LxWXrnkk=',

    'VERIFYING_KEY' : 'MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBALZ+WuuTIol2cwEALcqn+/d0AER+sX269KVZt7sdl9C0QcspNHvHGYBWLoYIV5i72fsINX4V5IvkqsIn83O4jQMCAwEAAQ=='
}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ]
}
```

Views and Other Using [Djoser Package](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)

`Request POST | http://localhost:8000/api/jwt/create/`

```
 username : userExample,
 password : **********
```

> Note : Using Postman for testing

Answer (score 1):

It's Fixed , i'm only need to change ***SIGNING KEY & VERIFYING KEY*** string

Settings.py

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
        'SIGNING_KEY' : '''-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
''',

    'VERIFYING_KEY' : '''-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCpjDCwMjok1ez1Hr+eOnCs7Ms/
hczI1pZ3txyGKrMPLN2Tof3sgtW6fBOlpCctNo3rG00V64SDLbXHx59QTo+GBY8E
dVY8KnGy8ihMpBX86aD2SngP/pGXMBw/XjCvu7uXCQs0I52EfXmK1+/u5LgGFLiz
N1upQIcaJq3hm2KZPwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
''',
}
```

Comment: Well done.  And while I'm sure this is a key you don't intend on using for a long time, you probably shouldn't post it.   It it possible you will continue to use it, and also that someone else will copy/paste this.  It should be enough to just say `"SIGNING_KEY": "{private-key-here}"` and so on

Comment: thanks, this is only dummy key....i'm not use this key for my project